# Basic Jquery selector traversing

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to submit a form once a div 'tweet' has been clicked. Simple enough but i can't get it to work. Nothing happens on click. Don't think i'm navigating to the correct selector. The html sample below has many 'tweet' instances but all with different "values" that i want to send via post

html

```
<div id="tweet">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <form id="posticon" method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="srch_term" id="srch_term" value="John">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#tweet', function(){
    $(this).children("#posticon").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: **Crime Alert:** Duplicate `ID`s.

Comment: How and where do you want submit a form without taking any action? As Andreas and Praveen already pointed out You also can not have many `tweet` instances  having the same ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use an `id` once in a page, so use a `.tweet` class instead.

Secondly, jQuery's `.children()` method is used to get direct children (i.e. it doesn't go more than one level deep), so use `.find()` instead, which goes deeper than one level.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".tweet").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".posticon").submit();
  });

  //to check if the form was successfully submitted
  $(".posticon").submit(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).children("input").val();
    alert(inputValue + "'s form was submitted");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tweet">
  John's Tweet
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <form class="posticon" method="POST" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="srch_term" id="srch_term" value="John">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tweet">
  Michael's Tweet
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <form class="posticon" method="POST" action="">
          <input type="hidden" name="srch_term" id="srch_term" value="Michael">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info on [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the jQuery website.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent info.. I know all IDs should be unique aswell. Consider this as a brain fart. Sorry.
I was not aware of the children/find difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#tweet', function(){
 $("#posticon").trigger("submit");
 });
});
```